# Usage of "coruscating"

Tags: verbs, adjectives, word-usage

Can coruscating be used as a one word adjective to describe "interesting and exciting"?

Basically the usage is "his interesting and exciting research work" which will end up as "his coruscating research work".

Referring to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coruscating) gives this:

> coruscate
>   verb (used without object), coruscated, coruscating.
>   1. to emit vivid flashes of light; sparkle; scintillate; gleam.

So does this mean "coruscating" cannot be used with an object (research in this case)?

Comment: Coruscating: › formal extremely clever and exciting or humorous. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/coruscating

Comment: I've got a soft spot in my heart for "*irradiating*", because of this quote by Alexander Smith: "*It is not so much consequence what you say, as how you say it. Memorable sentences are memorable, on account of some single irradiating word.*".  That said, the word most commonly used in your context is "*galvanizing*" (meaning motivating to action), and sometimes "*bracing*" (as in the shock of jumping into cold water).

Comment: How about "luminary research"? Is it proper usage?

Comment: _Research_ is **not** an object in your example. There is nothing grammatically wrong with _coruscating research_, though I for one find it quite an odd choice of words. Then again, I find @Dan’s _galvanising research_ somewhat jarring, too—Google seems to agree that this is mostly used as a verbal, rather than adjectival participle, i.e., in a context like “We support galvanising [further] research into XYZ”, rather than “This is some very galvanising research”.

Comment: @Arpith: As a metaphor to a light in the dark, "luminary research" would be just fine.  "Illuminating research" is more common, though.  "Luminary" or "leading light" are used more to describe the researcher than the research itself.

Comment: @Arpith: I think I'm detecting a theme here.  You want to say the research *shines like a light*, and should be recognized as *exceptional* and *superior*. Have you considered "*his **brilliant** research*"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "coruscating" can be used as a one-word adjective to describe something "interesting and exciting" more particularly "sparkling" - from the Latin *coruscare*, meaning "to flash or vibrate".

However be careful. "Coruscating" has come in recent times (and it seems the OED has not yet caught up with the semantic shift) to mean "scathing" as in "coruscating criticism".
As [this article from last Sunday's *Observer*](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2023/sep/10/misusing-words-can-change-their-dictionary-definitions-coruscating#:%7E:text=Grayson%20Perry%27s%20%E2%80%9Ccoruscating%20repartee,a%20reader%20to%20cry%20foul%3F) by the *Guardian* and *Observer*'s global readers' editor Elisabeth Ribbans explains.

I am not clear if the semantic shift applies to the verb as well as the adjective. But the above editor certainly accepts "corruscating (scathing) criticism of Boris Johnson, at least from a semantic viewpoint, to be acceptable modern usage.

Comment: I think the adjective "coruscating" is much more common than the verb, so on the one hand, any change in meaning in the verb is likely to follow "coruscating", but on the other people are more likely to use the verb in strange, non-standard, or idiosyncratic ways. Most likely readers will be able to grok from context if it's insulting or not.

Answer (score 1):

What a horrible “dictionary”!

That’s just saying that *coruscate* is an intransitive verb, so you can’t *coruscate anything.

It has nothing to do with participial adjectives, like *coruscating wit*.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what does the asterisk denote when ELU users prefix a word with it?

Comment: @DanBron Here, it indicates an ungrammatical or impossible word or construction of some sort. This is the ***bogosity asterisk,*** and it is not so much an ELU habit as it is one of general linguistics literature. Note however that there is another quite distinct use that linguists routinely make of “asterisk(ed) words”: a reconstructed or inputed or deduced word that the writer thinks may (or must) have existed but for which no direct written evidence actually exists, such as some hypothetical PIE word. That one is the ***hypothetical asterisk.***

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful (and, unsurprising coming from you, both clear and comprehensive).